# Modifying Excel Layout with Visual Studio (SSIS prefered)

Tags: excel, visual-studio-2012, layout, ssis

I was wondering if it is possible to modify the layout of an excel document by using SSIS or something similar in Visual Studio.

With modifying the layout I mean things like hiding columns and changing column/row width or height.

Comment: Why not use the VBA in Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a script task with visual basic language allowed running Excel macro's which can be used for the layout.